# Circular Arrow in SVG and HTML5, ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, svg

I would like to draw circular arrow image using SVG. 
I'm new bee to the SVG language and trying to understand how the x,y and rx and ry works.

I did try playing around with the following SVG link to get the circular arrow as per my project, but no success so far!. 
any help to point me to right direction would be appriciated.
![enter image description here][1]

My code is here ('im using the code mvc view file) , to create two half curricular arrows, but cannot break them in to more than 2 arrows.

```
@functions {
    public static string pol(double progress, double radius)
    {
        return (Math.Sin(progress * Math.PI * 2.0) * radius).ToString("0.0") + "," + (Math.Cos(progress * Math.PI * 2.0) * -radius).ToString("0.0");
    }
}



<div>
     @{
                var prog = 0.20;
                var nib = 0.02;
                var pad = 0.02;

                var large1 = prog > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
                var large2 = (prog + pad + nib) > 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
            }




  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-102 -102 204 204">
        @if (prog <= float.Epsilon)
        {
            <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 1,1 0,100 A 100,100 0 1,1 0,-100 M 0,-80 A 80,80 0 1,0 0,80 A 80,80 0 1,0 0,-80" class="progressbar-background"></path>
        }
        else if (prog >= 1f - float.Epsilon)
        {
            <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 1,1 0,100 A 100,100 0 1,1 0,-100 M 0,-80 A 80,80 0 1,0 0,80 A 80,80 0 1,0 0,-80" class="progressbar-progress"></path>
        }
        else
        {
            <path d="M @pol(0, 100.0) A 100,100 0 @large1,1 @pol(prog, 100.0) L @pol(prog + nib, 90.0) L @pol(prog, 80.0) A 80,80 0 @large1,0 @pol(0, 80.0) L @pol(nib, 90.0) Z" class="progressbar-progress"></path>
            if (prog < 1 - pad - nib)
            {
                <path d="M @pol(prog + pad, 100.0) A 100,100 0 @large2,1 @pol(1 - pad, 100.0) L @pol(1 - pad + nib, 90.0) L @pol(1 - pad, 80.0) A 80,80 0 @large2,0 @pol(prog + pad, 80.0) L @pol(prog + pad + nib, 90.0) Z" class="progressbar-background"></path>
            }
        }
    </svg>
   </div>
```

Comment: Out put should be able to look like the following image    link                                                                    http://www.google.co.nz/imgres?imgurl=http://superawesomevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/arrow-circle-icon.jpg&imgrefurl=http://superawesomevectors.com/arrow-circle-icon/&h=566&w=800&tbnid=sPGyDQGU_Jf-_M:&zoom=1&docid=6RRKneJS2b-ZZM&ei=2ToiVbyuF83d8AWlvoDwCA&tbm=isch&ved=0CC4QMygTMBM

Answer (score 0):

I have created circular arrow image with the help of SVG tutorial. Article is posted to the above question which is what exactly Im looking to create in my application.

[Original article to the circular arrow image article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/990090/Circular-Arrows-Using-SVG-in-Razor?msg=5056014#xx5056014xx)

First I have created a HTML function as exactly explained in the article.

The below formula gives us the power to calculate the x and y coordinate for any point on a circle given the radius, r, of the circle and the angle, a, of the point we want. 
The value returned by the below function will be used to draw an arc of a circle and then I have added SVG element inside the same view page as below.

```
    @functions
    {
        public static string pol(double progress, double radius)
        {
          return (Math.Sin(progress * Math.PI * 2.0) * radius).ToString("0.0") + "," 
         + (Math.Cos(progress * Math.PI * 2.0) * -radius).ToString("0.0");
        }
    }

@{
    var nib = 0.02;
    var pad = 0.02; // padding between the arrows
    var large = 0; //large-arc-flag
    var rx = 100;
    var ry = 80;
    var rmid = (rx + ry) / 2;

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-102 -102 204 204" class="progressbar-graphic">

        @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var start = i * 0.2 + pad / 2; 
            var end = (i + 1) * .2 - pad / 2;

            var classarrow = "progressbar-progresspink ";
            if (i == 0) {
                classarrow = "progressbar-progressred";
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                classarrow = "progressbar-progressgreen";
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                classarrow = "progressbar-progressyellow";
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                classarrow = "progressbar-progresspink";
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                classarrow = "progressbar-progressblue";
            }
            <path d="M @pol(start, @rx) 
                     A @rx,@rx 0 @large,1 @pol(end, @rx) 
                     L @pol(end + nib,@rmid) 
                     L @pol(end, @ry) 
                     A @ry,@ry 0 @large,0 @pol(start, @ry) 
                      @pol(start + nib, @rmid) Z" 
                    class=@classarrow>
            </path>

        }
    </svg>

}
```

Explanation:

  1. I have divided circle in to 5 sections, so that I can see 5 circular arrows. Hence the for loop for 5 times.

  2. Now, I'm considering 5 circulars arrows as percentage of 0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%.

  3. As per the above point (2), I'm passing the "progress" parameter of the POL function, as 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 in a loop, where as radius is set to constant i.e (rx = 80, ry =100).

  4. From the SVG Path code, we can understand drawing path as:
          M  move to certain point
          A  draw an large arc
          L  draw an slant line
          L  draw a line towards back
          A  draw an inner arc
          L  draw an line
          Z  close the path (which draws line back to the starting point)

  5. I’m using custom "class" to fill different colours. These classes can be defined inside your style.css file.

Comment: Any chances you can post your solution instead of the link to the tutorial?

Comment: Thank you for guiding me, I have edited my answer now with the essential parts required to draw an svg image.